# Preserve the formatting in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
import bs4

foo = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>This is heading1</h1>
        <p>
            This is a paragraph1
        </p>
        <h2>
            This is heading2
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>"""

def remove_p(text):
    obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
    for tag in obj.find_all("p"):
        tag.decompose()
    return str(obj)

foo = remove_p(foo)
print(foo)
```

```
beautifulsoup4 4.11.0
bs4            0.0.1
```

1. bs4 inserts blank lines corresponding to `<p>`. I expected entries corresponding to `<p>` tag to be deleted - no blank lines.
2. bs4 removes the leading spaces for opening tags. However, it doesn't remove leading spaces for closing tags `</h2>` and text.

I would like the function to return text with `<p>` entries removed without modifying the formatting. Please suggest.

Actual output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h1>This is heading1</h1>

<h2>
            This is heading2
        </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected Output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>This is heading1</h1>
        <h2>
            This is heading2
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Thanks for all the suggestions to use prettify(). I have already tried using prettify() but it completely changes the formatting of the document. Excuse me for not mentioning it to start with.
To add some context, we receive these documents from our upstream, and we are supposed to just delete some nodes without changing the formatting.

Comment: I think BeautifulSoup is meant for parsing of HTML. Not for rendering/printing of HTML.

Comment: By definition,  most whitespace sequences in HTML are equivalent to one space. So your actual output and your expected output are equivalent and will render identically. If you really care about this you're going to have to write your own version of `prettify()`. I don't understand why you consider this important. But if you do, you do. Just accept that API authors may not share your priorities.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want, but there is a way to prettify the code: use `obj.prettify()` instead of `str(obj)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function Prettify that is built into BeautifulSoup

here is an example shown from the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) of BeautifulSoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
# <html>
#  <head>
#   <title>
#    The Dormouse's story
#   </title>
#  </head>
#  <body>
#   <p class="title">
#    <b>
#     The Dormouse's story
#    </b>
#   </p>
#   <p class="story">
#    Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
#     Elsie
#    </a>
#    ,
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
#     Lacie
#    </a>
#    and
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">
#     Tillie
#    </a>
#    ; and they lived at the bottom of a well.
#   </p>
#   <p class="story">
#    ...
#   </p>
#  </body>
# </html>
```